# How to echo json_decode array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, arraylist, echo

I have fetched json data from server and decode using json_decode(value, true);

using print_r function I got this array as output

```
Array
(
    [id] => 120
    [key] => 7ca04960a36dbb7f4b7c8607bb3
    [num] => 0
)

Array
(
    [id] => 121
    [key] => 7ca04960a36dccgki49g6dfg57
    [num] => 0
)
```

I want to display decoded data using while loop.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $json = json_decode($row['post_req'], true);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($json);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

ex:

```
id = 120,
key = 7ca04960a36dbb7f4b7c8607bb3,
num = 0
```

how can I print data ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the `while`loop you're using. Do you get any errors? No output? Wrong values? Did you try using [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited: It looks like you changed some details.

It looks like you are getting multiple arrays

```
$output = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $json = json_decode($row['post_req'], true);
    $ouput[] = $json;
}
```

This will give you a multi-layered array and if you just want the id you can do this

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($output); $i++) {
    echo "id =" . $output[$i]['id'] . " <br/>";
}
```

or you can use this to get id only

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($output); $i++) {
    foreach ( $output[$i] as $key => $value ) {
      if ('id' === $key) {
        echo "$key = $value <br />";
      }
    }
}
```

The expected output is

```
id = 120
id = 121
```

If you want all three values use this

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($output); $i++) {
    foreach ( $output[$i] as $key => $value ) {
      echo "$key = $value <br />";
    }
}
```

Expected output

```
id = 120
key = 7ca04960a36dbb7f4b7c8607bb3
num = 0
id = 121
key = 7ca04960a36dccgki49g6dfg57
num = 0
```

Comment: what is code if only wants to print perticular key value? i want to display only id

Comment: If you wanted the key only you would replace id with key and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($json as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value \n";
}
```

Comment: This will only work if you have a single-layered array, from the output above he is getting a multi-layered array.